# Get the value of a textnode which is being shown on the screen via javascript.Not very easy

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I mean, assume a web page is very long and contain lots of words, now i just want to get the value of a textnode which is being shown on the screen.How could i do it? Thanks! :)

what's more:
I mean, i know how to get the value of a textnode,but if a web page is very lage and contains thousands of words, what i want to do is that,only get the shown textnode of the dom tree.That means if you slither a mouse wheel,some text  disappear and some come into your vision.

Answer (score 1):

See the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:element.textContent) (DOM) and [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28VS.85%29.aspx) (IE) properties.

Or, in jQuery, use `$(elem).text();`

Answer (score 0):

var item = document.getElementById('elementId');
alert(item.value);